# Unable to retrieve results using pysolr.search() with grouping

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

Expected behavior:-
I expect to retrieve search results grouped by the specified field (sno) based on the provided query. The results should be similar to what I see in the Solr UI.

- Actual behavior:-
  No search results are returned. The results variable is empty.
- Steps to reproduce the behavior:-
  Use pysolr library to connect to Solr instance.Execute the following search query with grouping in Python:

results = solr.search(query, **{"group": "true", "group_field": "sno", "group_offset": 0,
"group_limit": 1, "group_sort": "date desc", "group_ngroups": "true", "rows": 1000})

- Alternatively, I tried the query below which gives me:
  (HTTP 400): [Reason: invalid boolean value: True]

results = solr.search(query, **{*"group":True*, "group_field": "sno", "group_offset": 0,
"group_limit": 1, "group_sort": "date desc", *"group_ngroups": True,* "rows": 1000})

Configuration
Operating system version: Windows 10
Search engine version:
Python version: 3.8
pysolr version: 3.9.0